# C#: Passing generic arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to write a method that checks, if a given x/y pair is a valid index for a 2nd array (eg check if `myArray[x,y]` is safe).

I would like it to work with arrays of any type, which I feel should be possible because they all have the same GetUpperBounds(int d) method and I do not need to touch their contents. I have tried

```
bool validate(<T>[,] array, int x, int y){ ... }
```

and

```
bool validate([,] array, int x, int y){ ... }
```

but that does not work.

Should I just keep overloading this method as needed even though the method bodies will be identical character for character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right syntax is:

```
bool validate<T>(T[,] array, int x, int y)
{
}
```

with the code inside that should be:

```
bool validate<T>(T[,] array, int x, int y)
{
    return x >= array.GetLowerBound(0) && x <= array.GetUpperBound(0) &&
        y >= array.GetLowerBound(1) && y <= array.GetUpperBound(1);
}
```

Or ignoring array that have a lower bound != 0... (you can create arrays that have the first index at 100, so that `myarray[100]` is the first element. It was done for compatibility with old VB probably. It isn't very used)

```
bool validate<T>(T[,] array, int x, int y)
{
    return x >= 0 && x < array.GetLength(0) &&
        y >= 0 && y < array.GetLength(1);
}
```

Comment: That was it! Could explain how the <T> between the method name and the open paren works, or a term I can look up?

Comment: @Weavermount That is the syntax of generics in C#: you put between the method name and the opening `(` a list of generic terms you will use (`<T>`, `<A, B>`, `<A, B, C>` and so on). The compiler sometimes can infer them so you don't have to explicitly write them when you **call** the method (in this case you can `validate(new double[5,5], 4, 4)`). Other times the compiler can't, so you have to call the method with explicit values: `validate<double>(new double[5,5], 4, 4)`